# In Inkscape, how can I save colors for use in multiple elements?

Tags: color, inkscape

For example, I'd like to have a color called "text-color" or one called "content-box-color". How can I save a color like this and then assign it to an element?

Answer (score 7):

Check out the wiki on [Inkscape swatches](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Release_notes/0.46#Swatches_panel.2C_color_drag-and-drop).

Also if this isn't what you're after, there is a free program called [Colorpic](http://www.iconico.com/colorpic/) which is a standalone program that can pick up a color from anywhere on your screen and save it in a labeled palette :)

I use it every day.

Comment: Inkscape swatches looks like what I want, but it seems that it has been in development for years without ever being completed.

Comment: Defiitely seems that way, that's why I offered up Colorpic too :)

Comment: But as I understand ColorPic does not help me assigning colors to a group of Inkscape elements?

Comment: Ah, no it doesn't. It's just a standalone colorpalette. I guess there isn't a way (afaik.) I rarely use Inscape.

Answer (score 1):

Simply click **Swatch** button in Fill & Stroke.

Comment: This is pretty useless because "The swatch button" is fairly meaningless. I found it though. Above the color selector, there's these rectangular buttons. In the group of the left, the second to last one, for me, it's next to a questionmark and a checker pattern. It looks like a square with a border. That's the swatch button.

Answer (score 1):

Swatches is definitely the way to go here and offers some very useful functionality. Once set up correctly, you can change one color setting and have the change instantly propagate to many different objects that use that same swatch color.

Here is a quick tutorial:
http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Attributes-Fill-Stroke.html#Attributes-CustomSwatches

Another tip: to rename your swatches dive in to the XML editor and look in the  element at the top.